# Array of struct in C to D

Tags: d, ctod

So i've tried to make my own PAWN sdk for D Programming Language, i know there are already PAWN sdk for D but i just want to try to make it by myself.

I got strange problem when i convert this C code to D:

```
struct tagAMX;
typedef cell (*AMX_NATIVE)(struct tagAMX *amx, cell *params);

typedef struct tagAMX_NATIVE_INFO {
const char *name;
AMX_NATIVE func;
} AMX_NATIVE_INFO;
```

And i've convert it to D code:

```
struct AMX;
alias AMX_NATIVE = cell function(AMX* amx, cell* params);

struct AMX_NATIVE_INFO {
    immutable(char)* name;
    AMX_NATIVE func;
}
```

Do i wrote it right?, if that code look fine, just ignore it.

The main problem is here: in C

```
AMX_NATIVE_INFO PluginNatives[] =
{
    {"HelloWorld", HelloWorld},
    {0, 0}
};
```

How do i write that on D? i tried with:

```
AMX_NATIVE_INFO[] NativeInfo =
[
    ["HelloWorld", HelloWorld],
    [0, 0] 
];
```

It just give me error:

```
function test.HelloWorld (AMX* amx, int* params) is not callable using argument types ()
cannot implicitly convert expression ([0, 0]) of type int[] to AMX_NATIVE_INFO
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```d
AMX_NATIVE_INFO[] NativeInfo =
[
    AMX_NATIVE_INFO("HelloWorld", &HelloWorld),
    AMX_NATIVE_INFO(null, null)
];
```

or

```d
AMX_NATIVE_INFO[] NativeInfo =
[
    {"HelloWorld", &HelloWorld},
    {null, null}
];
```

Read [this](http://dlang.org/spec/struct.html) for more details on structs.

Comment: Thank's man, actualy i've tried and didn't work, but i try it again after see your answer then works lol, thanks!

Comment: You probably forgot to take address of the function (`&`). Note that with D's [optional parentheses](http://dlang.org/spec/function.html#optional-parenthesis) just writing `HelloWorld` means invoking this function without arguments.